# What is the best practice of writing aspects in aop for single threaded and multithreaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have aop config as follows

```
aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="Intercepter" ref="aspect1">
            <aop:around pointcut="execution(* *..*ServiceImpl.*(..))"
                method="serviceIntercept" />

        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>

 <bean id="aspect1" class=Intercepter">

    </bean>

public class Intercepter

{
private String variable1;

    public Intercepter()
    {
    }

    public Object serviceIntercept(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
        throws Throwable
    {
 Object retVal = null;
        //Method M1 set value of variable1
        M1();
  // call actual Method on ServiceImpl
 retVal = pjp.proceed();
    }

public class AServiceImpl  {
Method1();
Method1(){
call Method2 on BServiceImpl from AServiceImpl
 BServiceImpl.Method2()
}

}

public class BServiceImpl  {
Method2();

}

Main(){
// call AServiceImpl assuming it is single threaded.
 AServiceImpl() 


}
```

So sequence is as follows

1.First call to AServiceImpl() from Main() it is intercepted and variable variable1 is set to variable1="test";
2.Now the actual method Method1() on AServiceImpl is called.

3.From Method1() again Method2() on  BServiceImpl  is called.So again it is intercepted.Previously value of variable1 is set to "test" and now this time it is set to "".So everytime it is intercepted the value of variable1 changed

**So, what is the best practice for writing aop so that it will be safe from multithread and single threaded program?**

.In this case it is singleton as class Intercepter is singleton and single threaded .So i can see the problem  writing aspect as singleton.Similarly the similar problem may occur in multithreaded program.May be writing aspect class as Immutable class Or Replacing singleton with prototype  can be solution in my understanding  .But ,i want to get more deeper ideas and information and  solution on  different approaches people use in their progaram.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to keep a state in singleton in a multi-threaded program is to use `ThreadLocal` variables.

In your case, you would have to replace `String variable1` with `ThreadLocal<String> variable1`.

When using `ThreadLocal`, you have to take care of clearing the value when its no longer in use. A good place is often a `finally` clause, as in :

```
try {
  variable1.set(...)
  pjp.proceed();
} finally {
  variable1.remove();
}
```